# replace white space with commas in lines that can contain forward slashes and dashes

Tags: regex, macos, textmate, regex-group, vcf-vcard

I am trying to replace white space in lines with text and forward slashes with commas without having a trailing comma on the end of the line.

I am using a text editor with separate find and replace strings.

the input looks like this (a few of the different variables):

```
CATEGORIES:ORION/AKC Collection accounts receivable White Plains 
CATEGORIES:ABITIBIBOWATER/NOA1 ENRON/NOA PAPERCO/CL DWA 
CATEGORIES:ONSITE FAO 
CATEGORIES:LAR-DAN Lar-Dan
```

the results should be:

```
CATEGORIES:ORION/AKC,Collection,accounts,receivable,White,Plains 
CATEGORIES:ABITIBIBOWATER/NOA1,ENRON/NOA,PAPERCO/CL,DWA 
CATEGORIES:ONSITE,FAO 
CATEGORIES:LAR-DAN,Lar-Dan
```

I tried:

```
CATEGORIES:([A-Z|a-z])*
```

but it only gets me the first expression

```
CATEGORIES:ORION (in the first example.
```

Comment: I don't know textmate but isn't "Find `SPACE`" and "Replace `,`" working?

Comment: from the example, it looks like all we need to do is find a single space and replace it with comma. or is there more to it?

Comment: I don't understand your regexp, what do you mean with `[A-Z|a-z]` ?  Shouldn't it be `[A-Za-z]` or you meant to include a vertical bar `|` in the set of matched characters.  As written, it means match any of uppercase letters, lowercase letters or the vertical bar `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex your tried `CATEGORIES:([A-Z|a-z])*` Matches `CATEGORIES:` followed by a capturing group repeated zero or more times with the ranges `a-z` and `A-Z` and also a `|` because they are in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). That would for example also match `CATEGORIES:ONSITE||`

what you might do is match CATEGORIES in a capturing group and use `\G` to get a iterative match where you capturing not a whitespace characters in the second capturing group followed by matching one or more times a space where the end of the string `$` does not follow.

`(CATEGORIES:|\G(?!^))(\S+)[ ]+(?!$)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I2ARzb/1)

And replace with the 2 capturing groups followed by a comma

`$1$2,`

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it does not look like you are replacing
1. white space in lines with text
2. forward slashes with commas

Whereas you expected output replaces white space in lines with commas

This you can achieve by searching for below pattern

```
(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)
```

and then simply replace this by a comma.

This will only search for white spaces surrounded by characters and ignore the spaces at the end followed by a newline character.

You can do this in any editor (tried it on notepad++ & vim)

In addition, if you want to achieve
1. white space in lines with text
2. forward slashes with commas

Then for #1, search for `(?<=\w)\s(?=\w)` in your file and replace it with the text you want.

And for #2 search for `\/` in your file and replace it with `,`